# grails springsecurity override accountLocked on register

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using springsecurity core 1.2 and spring security ui 0.2.  In a default setup with a registercontroller, a user can have the accountLocked set to true:

```
    def user = new User(username: username,
            enabled: true,
            password: password,
            accountExpired: false,
            accountLocked: true,
            passwordExpired: false)
```

in RegisterController.register a confirmation email is sent to the new user.  The email arrives, user clicks on the link in the email, and RegisterController.verifyRegistration sets the accountLocked = false for the user.

That's all default out of the box behavior, so I won't list all the relevant code.  The default behavior is to not allow a user to login until accountLocked = false.  If you register then come back later to login, an 'account locked' error is shown on the login form.

I would like to allow the user to login even if accountLocked is true (meaning they have not clicked the verify link in the confirmation email).  How can I do this without adding my own 'myAccountLocked' field?

I want to be able to control some of the user's account activity based on accountLocked, but they should still be able to login to access parts of their account prior to clicking the verification link in the email.

The one change I did make to the default install is I create the user during the registration process, not in the verification process.  My verification process just sets the accountLocked flag to false and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Security Core does some pre and post authentication checks. The locked validation is done in the [DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/1.x/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks.java) class, so you will need to substitute it:

```
class MyPreAuthenticationChecks implements UserDetailsChecker {
    protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor();
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public void check(UserDetails user) {
        if (!user.isEnabled()) {
            log.debug("User account is disabled");

            throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled",
        "User is disabled"), user);
        }

        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
            log.debug("User account is expired");

            throw new AccountExpiredException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired",
        "User account has expired"), user);
        }
    }
}
```

And in resources.groovy you declare the bean to use your class intead of Spring's one:

```
beans = {
  preAuthenticationChecks(MyPreAuthenticationChecks)
}
```